# Having a problem using the Ossila x200 LabVIEW driver to initialize the communication

Tags: usb, driver, labview

I am trying to establish a connection with the Ossila x200 using the LabVIEW driver. The HelloCloi Command requires you to choose between USB and Ethernet and enter an address.

My question is: What is the address? Is it the USB address on my laptop? And, if so, how could I find it?
[image]

Comment: With ethernet, you'd probably need the IP address. With USB, try 0 or 1 in the text constant. That sort of information is typically found in a manual. Did the dev kit come with documentation?

Comment: Open NI MAX (which is installed with any NI driver), and check this USB device in the list of devices. If it is there, copy its address to the VI. If it is not visible, then I guess there could be some issues with drivers (because device has to be visible when you connect it to PC).